# Ejecutar Geocoder sólo una vez

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Intente hacer que cuando el **Geocoder** obtenga una dirección deje de realizar actualizaciones y deje la última posición como variable. Lo que pasa es que cuando obtengo la ubicación actualizo automáticamente un **Tableview**, pero si el **Geocoder** trabaja todo el rato entonces no deja de actualizar el tableview y necesito que sólo se actualice una vez al obtener la dirección.

Este es el código:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let location = locations[0]

    let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01)
    let myLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)

    //print(location.altitude)
    //print(location.speed)

    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { (placemark, error) in
        if error != nil
        {
            print ("THERE WAS AN ERROR")
            self.placelocality = "null"
            self.placecountry = "null"
            print("\(self.placelocality) y \(self.placecountry)")
        }
        else
        {
            if let place = placemark?[0]
            {
                if let checker = place.subThoroughfare
                {
                    self.placelocality = place.locality!
                    self.placecountry = place.country!
                    //print("\(place.locality!) \n \(place.country!)")
                    if self.placelocality != "null" && self.placecountry != "null" {
                        self.ps = self.placecountry
                        self.cdad = self.placelocality
                        self.lblubicacion.text = "Selecciona en \(self.placelocality), \(self.placecountry)."

                        self.updatesearchbar()

                    } else {
                        self.ps = "País";
                        self.cdad = "Ciudad";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Espero puedan ayudarme, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Varia mucho de como tengas tu implementación, supongo que en alguna parte de tu código estas usando el `locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()` eso hace que siempre se este mandando llamar el didupdateLocations....

Mi sugerencia es quitar eso, y actualizar la locación del usuario cuando lo necesitas realmente usando `locationManager.requestLocation()`, esto mandara llamar una sola vez la petición de la ubicación del usuario y lanzara tu update con la posición actual....

````
Locations # 1: [<+XX.XXXXX,-XXX.XXXXXXX> +/- 65.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 5/24/19, 11:38:09 AM Pacific Daylight Time]```
````